# Mysql Left Outer Join on 3 tables failing

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables in my Mysql DB as follows:

**daily_data_update:**

```
----------------------------------------------
id      date      code   user_id  followup_status
----------------------------------------------
1     08/10/2020   AD123    1          1
2     08/10/2020   AD134    2          2
3     08/10/2020   AD123    1          1
---------------------------------------------
```

**users:**

```
-------------------------------------
id   first_name  user_region
------------------------------------
1     Peter      scotland
2     Susan      ireland
------------------------------------
```

**followupstatus**

```
------------------------------------
id  followup_status
---------------------------------------
1      Paid
2     Unpaid
----------------------------------------
```

I need to `select date,code and followup_status from daily_data_update WHERE user_id in users` along with followup_status. My query is as follows:

```
SELECT t1.`date`,
       t1.`code`,
       t3.`followup_status`
FROM `daily_data_update` AS t1,
     followupstatus AS t3
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL
  AND t2.user_region = 'scotland'
```

But the query is failing as `Unknown column 't1.user_id' in 'on clause'`

What is wrong with my query and how can i resolve it ?? Requesting help..

Comment: Don't use `,` joins but only proper `JOIN` joins.

Comment: Sorry, being a newbie i did not understand.

Comment: I tried the following and followup status is displaying NULL:
SELECT t1.`date`,t1.`code`,t3.`followup_status`
FROM `daily_data_update` AS t1
LEFT OUTER JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id
LEFT JOIN followupstatus AS t3 ON t1.`followup_status` = t3.followup_status
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL AND t2.user_region = 'scotland'

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.`date`,
       t1.`code`,
       t3.`followup_status`
FROM `daily_data_update` AS t1
LEFT JOIN followupstatus AS t3 ON t1.followup_status = t3.id
LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t1.user_id = t2.id
WHERE t2.id IS NOT NULL
  AND t2.user_region = 'scotland'
```

Hope this works!!

Comment: Followup_status is Displaying NULL

Comment: Can you share what output you are expecting?

Comment: the followup_status should be Paid or Unpaid as displayed in table in my question.

Comment: t1.followup_status = t3.followup_status should be t1.followup_status = t3.id

Comment: Thanks @P.Salmon